# Golang не видит axios

Tags: vue.js, golang, axios, vue-cli

В Golang принимаю данные

```
name := c.PostForm("name")
email := c.PostForm("email")
password := c.PostForm("password")
```

В vue отправляю данные, но golang не видит их.
Хотя если такое же делать с Ajax то все видит.
Так же тестил с fetch и так же не может принять.

принимаю запрос.

```
router.POST("/api/singup", singup)
```

использую библиотеку gin

То что возвращает axios
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проверьте 'Content-Type' там и там - он будет разный. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31758005/9435985

Comment: Проверил и они одинаковые. fmt.Println(c.GetHeader("Content-Type")) и там выводит application/json;charset=UTF-8 это тоже самое что и отправляю

Comment: Раз у вас JSON, зачем вы POST-форму читаете?

Comment: А как правильно читать ?

Comment: Раз у вас JSON, попробуйте использовать c.ShouldBind(&form), в структуре form опишите какие поля принимаете